# Can Ace Editor display labels next to the code?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am trying to display some information about the lines of code in Ace Editor.
Therefore I was wondering if there is the possibility to add info labels next or above the lines that are not really part of the code.

For example, in a JavaScript file, we could have:

`var x = "some string";`**assignment expression**

with some extra styling for the "assignment expression" text;
However, when the text is saved, I don't want the "assignment expression" to be part of the content.

I would be interested to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a CSS "after" psuedo-class?

Something like `.ace_line.foo:after {content: 'assignment expression';}`?

Answer (score 0):

You could tag different lines of code with class names, like give `var x = "some string";` the class "string assignment".

To tag the text with a class you could create your own mode-highlighter that inherits from whatever language you're using. This is an example that expands on c#

```
ace.define("ace/mode/custom_highlight_rules", ["require", "exports", "module", "ace/lib/oop", "ace/mode/text_highlight_rules", "ace/mode/behaviour/xml", "ace/mode/behaviour/cstyle"], function (require, exports, module) {
    "use strict";

    var oop = require("../lib/oop");
    var TextMode = require("../mode/text").Mode;
    var Tokenizer = require("../tokenizer").Tokenizer;
    var TextHighlightRules = require("./text_highlight_rules").TextHighlightRules;
    var CSharpHighlightRules = require("./csharp_highlight_rules").CSharpHighlightRules;

var Mode = function () {
    this.$tokenizer = new Tokenizer(new CustomHighlightRules().getRules());
}


var CusomHighlightRules = function() {
    this.embedRules(CSharpHighlightRules,
        "", [
            {
                token: "csharp.assignment",
                regex: "/[a-zA-A] *= *[a-zA-Z/

            },
            {
                token: "csharp.methodcall",
                regex: "/[a-zA-Z]+\(\)/

        ]);
```

This will make it tag all of your code that matches whatever regex you add with 
a class of your choice.

in this situation uit finds letters then a space or no and an equal sign and more letters. and gives it both classes csharp and ace_assignment (ace adds the ace_)

after that you can go into css and do :after psuedo-classes or jquery lookups.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I was looking to do something more dynamic, without having to define rules and without having to define another ace module. In the meantime I solved it using a tooltip.